# I was told that 25th line of code contains an issue where setState() with random color being used. Help identify an issue

Tags: flutter, dart, random, setstate

Original task sounded like:

> The application should: display the text "Hey there" in the middle of
> the screen and after tapping anywhere on the screen a background color
> should be changed to a random color. You can also add any other
> feature to the app - that adds bonus points Please do not use any
> external libraries for color generation

My solution ([GitHub](https://github.com/preckrasno/flutter-test-task)):

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: RandomBackgroundColorWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomBackgroundColorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomBackgroundColorWidget createState() => _RandomBackgroundColorWidget();
}

class _RandomBackgroundColorWidget extends State<RandomBackgroundColorWidget> {
  int _colorIndex = 0xFF42A5F5;

  void _randomColorIndexGenerator() {
    final _rng = new Random();
    setState(() => {_colorIndex = (_rng.nextInt(0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000)});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Material(
        color: Color(_colorIndex),
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Hey there"),
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _randomColorIndexGenerator(),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

While reviewing my test task interviewer said that **25th line of code contains an issue**.

```dart
setState(() => {_colorIndex = (_rng.nextInt(0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000)});
```

And he commented:

> "It is working in a way that is not intended by you."

Help to identify an issue in 25th line of code.

Comment: It honestly works fine as it is. Is it working how you intended it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in ***nextInt*** function.

Flutter accepts color codes for generation up to 0xFFFFFFFF, where first pair of numbers is needed for opacity level and other pairs needed for RGB levels [image: Colored HEX]

***nextInt*** function generates random number in range up to, but not including, passed number. For example, `nextInt(3)` will generate randomly 0,1 or 2, but not 3.

So original app was generating all random colors (from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFE) except last one - 0xFFFFFF

Therefore, 25th line should look like this in order to generate every possible color.

```dart
setState(() => _colorIndex = (_rng.nextInt(0x1000000) + 0xFF000000));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accidentally combining the two ways to declare a function in Dart: the arrow operator => and curly braces {}.

Line 25 should be:

```dart
setState(() => _colorIndex = _rng.nextInt(0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000);
```

with no extra curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a syntax error. When using setState() =>, you dont need the {}

```
setState(() {_colorIndex = (_rng.nextInt(0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000)});
```

or

```
setState(() => _colorIndex = (_rng.nextInt(0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000));
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the error you mention, however I recommend that you always use init state when assigning default values.

Here other way

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: RandomBackgroundColorWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomBackgroundColorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomBackgroundColorWidget createState() => _RandomBackgroundColorWidget();
}

class _RandomBackgroundColorWidget extends State<RandomBackgroundColorWidget> {
  Color _color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _color = Colors.white;
    super.initState();
  }

  void getrandomColor() {
    setState(() {
      _color = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Material(
        color: _color,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Hey there"),
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: getrandomColor,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```